# Getting "(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443" when starting Apache

Tags: httpd

My first reaction was to look at the listening ports on the machine. Nothing is running on port 443 (or 80, for that matter). Just my ports listening for sshd.

I am running Fedora 13 and it is a fresh install. I'm running the "httpd-2.2.16-1.fc13.x86_64.rpm" package.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, my error_log is outputting "Unable to open logs"

Comment: I have also disabled SELinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the package mentioned above and re-installed it via yum (as I had before) and it worked. Not sure what the issue was...